# Need to Return a Single Value from a Dictionary Key with Multiple Values (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, key

I have a data frame that I can't parse on position because it's not consistent, so I need to translate it to a dictionary. I need to take this dataframe

| index | TimeStamp1 | TimeStamp2 | Timestamp3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bird | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Snack | 4 | 5 | 6 |

and get these dictionary values:
Bird: 1
Snake: 4, 5, 6

Any advice on how to do this? I tried making a dictionary and orienting it on the dictionary but I can't figure out how to select a single value.

I'm starting with
yf.Ticker(ticker).quarterly_balance_sheet - which returns a dataframe
I need to be able to index the values of the dataframe. I am already using to_dict - what I can't figure out is how to pull one single value when there are three things assigned to the key.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary where you assign a list as a value of dictionary.

```
dict={"bird": [1,2,3], "snack": [4,5,6]}
#select a list from dictionary
print(dict["bird"])
#select an element from a value of list dict
print(dict["bird"][0])
```

Then you can access to a single element, or to all other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since it returns a `DataFrame`, you can use `to_dict` to obtain a dictionary like object.
Try this:

```py
msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
balance_sheet = msft.quarterly_balance_sheet
split_dict = balance_sheet.to_dict('split')
result = {
    key: split_dict['data'][idx] for idx, key in enumerate(split_dict['index'])
}
print(result)
# >> {"bird": [1,2,3], "snack": [4,5,6]}
```

Comment: I'm already using to_dict. What I can't figure out how to do is return one single value when there are three values assigned to the key.

Comment: Then I think the answer from @MichałMazur already serves the purpose `result["bird"] = [result["bird"][0]]`

Comment: Mmm, no, because when I convert it to a dictionary, there's the added information of the timestamp header, it doesn't just return the value - it returns Timestamp('2021-09-25 00:00:00'):6580000000.0,, not just 6580000000.0,.

Comment: The `to_dict()` function has different types of output depending on the model you give. my answer is using split and after some manual parsing it gives you something like this `{"bird": [1,2,3]}`. You can try making changes on top of my answer.